# SwiftUI - can't see navigation tabs when using TabView in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm following a tutorial for how to create my first iOS app, there is a step in it to add "TabView" around the `NavigationView` that surrounds the initial call that calls my content for the main page of the app, however I can't figure out why the tabs are not working.

My code matches the tutorial code. In the tutorial example, there is now a navigation at the bottom of the screen with an airplane icon and text that says "Location", however in my version I can only see the content that is on my main view `MainDashboardView.swift`, and the contents of the TabView do not show up at all.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct testApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TabView {
                NavigationView {
                    MainDashboardView()
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "airplane.circle.fill")
                    Text("Location")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At first I thought I was putting the `.tabItem` in the wrong spot, and I tried moving it under `TabView` instead of `NavigationView` like so:

```
TabView {
                NavigationView {
                    MainDashboardView()
                }
            }
            .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "airplane.circle.fill")
                    Text("Location")
                }
```

But that is incorrect, and doesn't match the documentation when I checked it.

It seems like it should simply work so I'm not sure why it isn't!

I'm simulating on an iPhone 13 and have tried in other phones also with the same results

**Edit** Also, I am not getting any errors

Comment: `NavigationView` should probably be inside of `MainDashboardView`.

Comment: Works fine on my side. May sound trivial, but try to clean build the project and restart both Xcode and the Simulator

Comment: @burnsi i can try it but in the tutorial the navigation info is all in the project's main file not in the subfiles of each view

Comment: @narek.sv Just tried it, it didn't work I still can only see the content of the view but not the tabview :(

Comment: strange! What's the iOS version of your simulator?

Comment: @narek.sv It's running iPhone 13 with iOS 15.4 at the moment

Comment: Do you run the app or just view it in the **Canvas** (`Previews`), maybe your `PreviewProvider` is constructed wrong.

Comment: @narek.sv I tried both, when I look in my Canvas Preview I can't see my `tabItems` at the bottom OR my top `toolbarItem` where I have the app logo, but when I do a build in the simulator I can see my top toolbar item but not the tab items at the bottom

Comment: @narek.sv Oh my gosh i figured it out!!! It was displaying but it was all the same color as my background so i couldn't see it WOW

Answer (score 0):

Well this is embarrassing, turns out it was working but the icon, text, and tabs were all white so I couldn't see them on my white background WOW!!!!

Turns out my accent color was set to white so the icons and nav text were all showing up as white on my white background